# Local Jekyll Serve/Live Site discrepancy

Tags: html, github, markdown, jekyll, github-flavored-markdown

I am creating a jekyll blog to host on my github.io account using a theme. The problem is simple: when I run 'jekyll serve' the site generates locally as it should with no issues. However, when I push it to my_profile.github.io repository, it is breaking online.

I'm confused as to why this is happening. I found one other question here on stack: [Locally building and pushing jekyll site to github pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36377865/locally-building-and-pushing-jekyll-site-to-github-pages). An answerer recommends pushing only the _site folder of jekyll that gets auto-generated. However, that didn't solve it for me.

Link to my repo if anyone wants to take a stab:
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36377865/locally-building-and-pushing-jekyll-site-to-github-pages](https://github.com/spirited-away/spirited-away.github.io)

Link to broken live page: https://spirited-away.github.io/

Any ideas appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're requesting assets with `http://`, but serving your site on `https://`. Browsers don't like that. Use your browser developer tools to see the errors.

Although I can't be sure without a repo URL, you've probably got something like this set in your `_config.yml`:

```
url: http://spirited-away.github.io/
```

Change it to:

```
url: https://spirited-away.github.io/
```