# Add new gem to jekyll site hosted on github

Tags: ruby, jekyll, github-pages

I have added `last_modified` gem to my local jekyll site and it works fine i.e. generates last updated time on pages. When I push my update file to remote site (hosted on github) it doesn't work.

**local**

[image: local site]

**github.io**

[image: on github]

Comment: Yes @deveth0 is right that Github uses only limited set of plugins. The solution is to build it locally like what deveth0 said. I would recommend you look at this article tho http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28249255/how-do-i-configure-github-to-use-non-supported-jekyll-site-plugins/28252200#28252200

Comment: yes. got it. thanks

Comment: actually, I have written a bash script to modify file before commit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Github only supports a limited set of [plugins](https://pages.github.com/versions/). If you want to use any other plugins, you have to build the Jekyll site locally and then push the html to Github (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36377865/locally-building-and-pushing-jekyll-site-to-github-pages) ).